# Action listener, to change images on click.

Tags: java

I have some images that i need to change on click, right now there is only three images of each category, 3 noses, 3 eyes and 3 mouths. So i took this approach to my solution, however i realize this is not the best way to go about it because the number of images is hard coded i would like it to change dinamically. Im in need of some ideas, or suggestions.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    private int nose  = 1;
    private int mouth = 1;
    private int eyes = 1;   

    Color[] color ={Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.PINK,Color.CYAN,Color.WHITE};
    static int colorCounter =1 ;

    public ImagePanel() {

    }

    public void changeNose(){
        nose = ++nose % 3;
        nose++;
    }
    public void changeMouth(){
        mouth = ++mouth % 3;
        mouth++;
    }
    public void changeEyes(){
        eyes = ++ eyes % 3;
        eyes++;
    }   

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.green);
        g.setColor(color[colorCounter]);
        g.fillOval(40, 120, 400, 400);


        ImageIcon hat = new ImageIcon
                (ImagePanel.class.getResource("/a06Face/Images/santa.png"));
            hat.paintIcon(this, g, 160, 3);

        ImageIcon eyes1 = new ImageIcon
                (ImagePanel.class.getResource("/a06Face/Images/eyes"+eyes+".png"));
        eyes1.paintIcon(this, g,180, 200);

        ImageIcon nose1 = new ImageIcon(ImagePanel.class.getResource("/a06Face/Images/nose"+nose+".png"));
            nose1.paintIcon(this, g, 180, 300);

        ImageIcon mouth1 = new ImageIcon
                (ImagePanel.class.getResource("/a06Face/Images/mouth"+mouth+".png"));
        mouth1.paintIcon(this, g, 170, 400);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your problem bit more? I am not clear on what you are going to do? What does it mean by 3 noses, mouths etc?

Comment: I have three different png files named, nose1, nose2, nose3 . And i want to switch through them every time i click, so what i have done its use the modulus operator to keep the number of images from going past 3, hence i would not go out of bounds. But as you can see my changeEyes, changeMouth, changeNose are hard coded to work with 3 images. I'd like to implement a different way to do this, i noticed that if i want to add another image i have to change the field values and the method values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MouseListener. 
How to do this:

```js
//in your Class constructor
public XYZ()
{
.....
Timer t = new Timer(0,new Listener());
t.start();
addMouseListener(new Mouse());
// later in program
private class Mouse extends MouseAdapter
{
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
<object>.doMethod(e.<otherMethod>);
}
}
```

This is just how to use a generic MouseListener. Modify this to fit your program.

Comment: I cant use a mouseListener because im not familiar with it, ihave figured out how to do it on a JButton event listener. The program works as intended but i think its poor design that i have hard coded the number of png files that im working with.

Comment: I would suggest getting more familiar with it for future reference. Let me come up with a different solution. You can read more about MouseListener here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's try this out. Let's define an instance field which holds all the image items in our system. This may be something like,

```
private List<ImageIcon> imgIcons = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>;
```

Then write a method to add image icons to this list. It may look like this.

```
private void addImageIcon(ImageIcon imgIcon){
    this.imgIcons.add(imgIcon);
}
```

Call this method from anywhere you need to add the images. Then you can get the size of the array when you need to count the number of images in this panel. Hope this helps. Happy Coding !

Comment: my (imgIcon) its just the path to my image, correct? because im getting an error saying "not applicable to the arguments (String)"

Comment: either way is fine. You can send the path and create the ImageIcon inside the method or pass the icon here and just add it to the list. I think previous way is better. Just send the path, create an ImageIcon and add it to the list inside the method.

Comment: got it, i'll give it a go.